# Cursor Application Issues

Tags: c#, winforms, imagemagick, jpeg

*So I'm trying to create an application that displays all the cursors in the folder C:\Windows\Cursors and allows the user to click on an image of the cursor they want and have it applied. Thanks for reading.*

*I've been trying to convert the .cur file to .jpeg because I think this is the reason that it is not being displayed under flowLayoutPanel1 but it is still not working.*

```
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using ImageMagick;

namespace CrossHare
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern bool SystemParametersInfo(int uiAction, int uiParam, IntPtr pvParam, int fWinIni);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        private static extern IntPtr LoadCursorFromFile(string lpFileName);

        private const int SPI_SETCURSORS = 0x0057;
        private const int SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE = 0x01;
        private const int SPIF_SENDCHANGE = 0x02;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Get the file paths of all files in the directory
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Windows\Cursors");

            // Iterate through the file paths
            foreach (string file in files)
            {
                // Check if the file is an image file
                if (!file.EndsWith(".cur")) continue;

                try
                {
                    // Create a new button
                    Button btn = new Button();
                    //Convert cur file to jpeg
                    using (MagickImage image = new MagickImage(file))
                    {
                        string jpegFile = Path.ChangeExtension(file, ".jpeg");
                        image.Format = MagickFormat.Jpeg;
                        image.Write(jpegFile);
                        using (Image img = Image.FromFile(jpegFile))
                        {
                            btn.Tag = file;
                            btn.Image = img;
                        }
                    }
                    btn.Size = new Size(100, 100);
                    btn.Click += Button_Click;
                    flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(btn);
                }
                catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
                {
                    // Handle file not found exception
                    MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);
                }
                catch (OutOfMemoryException ex)
                {
                    // Handle out of memory exception
                    MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Handle button click event
            MessageBox.Show("Button clicked!");
            // Get the selected file's path
            string filePath = ((Button)sender).Image.Tag as string;

            // Set the selected file as the "normal select" pointer in "Mouse properties"
            RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Control Panel\\Cursors", true);
            key.SetValue("Arrow", filePath);
            key.Close();
            IntPtr hCursor = new IntPtr((int)LoadCursorFromFile(filePath));
            SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETCURSORS, 0, hCursor, SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE | SPIF_SENDCHANGE);

        }

        private void UploadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            openFileDialog.Filter = "Cursor files (*.cur)|*.cur|All files (*.*)|*.*";
            openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
            if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                // Get the selected file's path
                string filePath = openFileDialog.FileName;
                // Do something with the file (e.g. upload it to a server)
                string destinationPath = @"C:\Windows\Cursors";
                string destinationFilePath = Path.Combine(destinationPath, Path.GetFileName(filePath));
                if (File.Exists(destinationFilePath))
                {
                    DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("File already exists, do you want to overwrite it?", "File Exists", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
                    if (result == DialogResult.No)
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                }
                File.Copy(filePath, destinationFilePath, true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you actually trying to change the extension of a files, hoping that it also changes its format? -- You can load a cursor with `new Cursor([Path of cursor])`, then use its `Draw()` method to draw it to a Bitmap sized as `[Cursor].Size`

Comment: Note that disposing / destroying (as what hCursor points to) resources you create is not optional. You really have to

Comment: Your question is receiving some downvotes - here's what might help: Try focusing the question title. Something like **How to display clickable cursor images in a FlowLayoutPanel** for example. Then, read the guidelines for a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You could probably get your point across using less code than you have here. You have a decent question, but consider making a few edits to improve your chances of getting quality responses _and_ have it be more generally useful to others having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

After carefully reading your code, if I'm following correctly your objectives are:

- Display all the available cursors in a `FlowLayoutPanel`.
- Click on an image to change the current cursor.

What we end up with here could be considered an [X-Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) because doing that is straightforward, but the manner in which you're trying to solve your problem is not.

Please allow me to steer the conversation back to what you were trying to do to begin with:

[image: screenshot]

---

To achieve this objective, use reflection to obtain the cursors from the `Cursors` class, draw each one, and place a corresponding button in the `FlowLayoutPanel`.

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()=>InitializeComponent();
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        foreach (PropertyInfo pi in typeof(Cursors).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public))
        {
            if(pi.GetValue(null) is Cursor cursor)
            {
                var image = new Bitmap(100, 100);
                using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(image))
                {
                    cursor.DrawStretched(
                        graphics,
                        new Rectangle(new Point(), new Size(image.Width, image.Height)));
                }
                var button = new Button
                {
                    Size = image.Size,
                    BackgroundImage = image,
                    BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch,
                    Margin = new Padding(5),
                    Tag = cursor,
                };
                button.Click += onAnyClickCursorButton;
                // Avoid confusion - see note.
                button.MouseHover += (sender, e) => Cursor = Cursors.Default;
                flowLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(button);
            }
        }
    }
```

By attaching a `Click` event to each button, the current `Cursor` can be changed to the one clicked. To avoid visual confusion, if a different button is hovered over then return to the default cursor to more clearly indicate that the new style can now be clicked.

```
    private void onAnyClickCursorButton(object? sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if((sender is Button button) && (button.Tag is Cursor cursor)) 
        {
            Cursor = cursor;
        }
    }
}
```